# Split string in a field and use as new column name in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I have a column `section` which has fields with string separators. It looks like :

```
"part1>part2>part3>part4"
```

I want to write a sql where in I can split the column `section` and pick the second element `part2` and assign it to a new field called say `output1`.

how can this be done.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer will probably use product specific string functions.)

Comment: Do you mean to a new _column_ output1?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I did add the tag and yes as a new column output1

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT    SPLIT(section, '>')[safe_ordinal(2)] AS `part2`, 
 FROM datatable
```